# Is it possible to track progress of lazy loaded modules?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, angular-material, lazy-loading

It's possible to monitor the progress of XHR requests using the HttpClient to determine the % complete. Is it also possible to listen to the download progress of lazy loaded modules?

Listening to router events for instances of `RouteConfigLoadStart` and `RouteConfigLoadEnd` is great, but gives you no information about the % loaded, and all the information I'm finding online involves some solution using these router events.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate"
                      *ngIf="loadingModules"
                      style="position: absolute; z-index: 10;">
    </mat-progress-bar>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public loadingModules: boolean;

  construction(private router: Router) { }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
     let loadingModules: number = 0;

     this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
        if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
          loadingModules++;
        }
        if (event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
          loadingModules--;
        }
        this.isLoadingModules = !!loadingModules;
     });
  }
}
```

This method will reliably show a progress bar while there are any lazy loaded modules still downloading, however, my aim is to show a determinate progress bar reflecting the download status. This is mainly to provide users with relatively slower connections a better UX.

Comment: Since this may not be something you can do right now, think about using a spinner, or some other indicator for long running downloads.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you're right about that. I've been writing in angular since the beginning and I've looked around quite a bit. I was just hoping there would be some creative way or something I missed in the docs. Thanks for the advice though!

Comment: It would be nice to have something a little more granular than just start and end for the events. Another thing to think about is making the modules small enough that they download quickly. Good luck!